# Nodejs - Express - How to calculate the next closer time to today()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I need to calculate which is the next closer hour to "time" taking into account the following array data:

```
var date = new Date();
var time = date.getHours(); // 17 -> it means 5:00 PM
var minute = date.getMinutes(); // 12

// This is how the data has been saved in the database.
{ id: ‘1’, time: '1:00 AM' }
{ id: ‘1’, time: '2:00 PM' }
{ id: ‘1’, time: '7:00 PM' }
{ id: ‘1’, time: '10:00 PM' }
{ id: ‘1’, time: '8:00 PM' }
{ id: ‘1’, time: '11:00 AM' }
{ id: ‘2’, time: '9:00 AM' }
{ id: ‘2’, time: '6:30 PM' }
{ id: ‘2’, time: '5:00 PM' }
{ id: ‘2’, time: '1:00 PM' }
```

The result need to be an array like this:

```
{id: ‘1’, time: '7:00 PM'}
{id: ‘2’, time: '6:30 PM'}
```

Basically I need to know which is the next closer time to 5:12 PM for each ID.

This is my code so far:

```
function calculateNextPill(items) {
let nextPillArr = [];
let itemData = null;
let item_id = null;
var currentTime = new Date();
var closerTime = new Date();    
var newTimes = [];
for(i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
    itemData = items[i].itemdata[0];
    item_id = items[i]._id;

    for (const prop in itemData.pills) {
        const pill = itemData.pills[prop];
        if (pill != undefined && pill.time != undefined) {
            nextPillArr.push({id: item_id, time: pill.time});
        }
    }
}
nextPillArr.forEach(element => {
    var time =  element.time;
    var scheduleTime = new Date();
    var parts = time.match(/(\d+):(\d+) (AM|PM)/);
    if (parts) {
        var hours = parseInt(parts[1]),
            minutes = parseInt(parts[2]),
            tt = parts[3];
        if (tt === 'PM' && hours < 12) hours += 12;
        scheduleTime.setHours(hours, minutes, 0, 0);
        var a = moment(currentTime);
        var b = moment(scheduleTime);
        b.diff(a);
        newTimes.push({id: element._id, diff: b.diff(a)});
        // here I need to calculate which time is closer for which pill. Not done yet. Need more coffe...
    }
});
```

}

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: I would suggest sorting your items by time and then iterating over the sorted items until you come to a larger time. If you give it a try perhaps someone can help you find the right solution.

Comment: You could  parse the date (maybe using ```Date.parse()```) for each element in your list and for each of them substract Date.now(), this will let you know how many milliseconds are left to reach the date and  finally pick the lower value which will be the closest one.

Comment: I will publish my code in a few minutes. It is a real mess...

Comment: Also, what does "closer" mean? If your "target time" is 6:00 PM... which is closer... 5:50 PM or 6:10 PM?

Comment: Sorry, 6:10PM is closer. Is like a schedule system that must show you the closer time to take the next pill..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need a function that lets you get some kind of numeric value for each time that you can then use to compare the values. The following function will give us the amount of minutes in 24h format:

```js
function time_to_numeric(time) {
    const [_, h, m, meridian] = time.match(/(\d+):(\d+) (AM|PM)/);
    let [hours, min] = [parseInt(h), parseInt(m)];
    if (meridian === "PM" && hours !== 12) hours += 12;
    if (meridian === "AM" && hours === 12) hours -= 12;
    return hours * 60 + min;
}
```

Next, we also need the time in the same format for `now`:

```js
const now = new Date();
const now_numeric = now.getHours() * 60 + now.getMinutes();
```

Using this, we can now start finding the closest times for each unique id assuming `items` is an array of all the objects in your example. This works by computing the difference in minutes to `now` and swapping the value if it lower. In the case of a time occuring earlier than now, we instead compute the difference to that time the next day. We save both the difference and the actual time for the current minimum for each id:

```js
const closer_times_by_id = items.reduce((acc, {id, time}) => {
    const time_numeric = time_to_numeric(time);
    let diff = time_numeric - now_numeric;
    if (diff < 0) diff = time_numeric + MINUTES_PER_DAY - now_numeric;
    const prev_diff = acc[id] && acc[id].diff;
    if (prev_diff === undefined || diff < prev_diff) {
        acc[id] = { diff, time };
    }
    return acc;
}, {});
```

Now our `closer_times_by_id`  will look something like `{'1': {diff: 158, time: '7:00 PM'}, '2': {diff: 38, time: '5:00 PM'}}`. We map this to an array in the following way:

```js
times_arr = Object.entries(closer_times_by_id).map(item => {
    const [id, { time }] = item;
    return { id, time };
});
```

After this, we are done and `times_arr` contains your result.

---

Full code:

```js
const MINUTES_PER_DAY = 24 * 60;

// Takes a string like '1:10 PM' and returns the amount of minutes in 24h format
function time_to_numeric(time) {
    const [_, h, m, meridian] = time.match(/(\d+):(\d+) (AM|PM)/);
    let [hours, min] = [parseInt(h), parseInt(m)];
    if (meridian === "PM" && hours !== 12) hours += 12;
    if (meridian === "AM" && hours === 12) hours -= 12;
    return hours * 60 + min;
}

function closest_items_by_id(items) {
    const now = new Date();
    const now_numeric = now.getHours() * 60 + now.getMinutes();

    // Find closest times for each id, giving preference to times in the
    // future in case of ties
    // After reducing has finished, closer_times_by_id will be an object like
    // {'1': {diff: 158, time: '7:00 PM'}, '2': {diff: 38, time: '5:00 PM'}}
    const closer_times_by_id = items.reduce((acc, {id, time}) => {
        const time_numeric = time_to_numeric(time);
        let diff = time_numeric - now_numeric;
        // If time occured earlier than now, calculate diff to time next day
        if (diff < 0) diff = time_numeric + MINUTES_PER_DAY - now_numeric;
        const prev_diff = acc[id] && acc[id].diff;
        if (prev_diff === undefined || diff < prev_diff) {
            acc[id] = { diff, time };
        }
        return acc;
    }, {});

    // Map closer_times_by_id to desired format
    return Object.entries(closer_times_by_id).map(item => {
        const [id, { time }] = item;
        return { id, time };
    });
}


const raw_data = [
    { id: '1', time: '1:00 AM' },
    { id: '1', time: '11:00 AM' },
    { id: '1', time: '2:00 PM' },
    { id: '1', time: '7:00 PM' },
    { id: '1', time: '8:00 PM' },
    { id: '1', time: '10:00 PM' },
    { id: '2', time: '9:00 AM' },
    { id: '2', time: '1:00 PM' },
    { id: '2', time: '1:10 PM' },
    { id: '2', time: '5:00 PM' },
    { id: '2', time: '6:30 PM' },
]

const now = new Date();
console.log(`Time at SO-server: ${now.getHours()}:${now.getMinutes()}`);
console.log(closest_items_by_id(raw_data));
```

Comment: first at all, you rock dude. Thank you very much for al this code!! On the other hand, I just tested it by running on code snipped and I guess the result was wrong.

This is what I got when the time NOW is 16:22 PM
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "time": "2:00 PM"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "time": "5:00 PM"
  }
]

Id 1 should return 7PM instead 2PM. It is closer in the future, not closed in general.
Id 2 worked because 16:22 PM is closer to 5 PM than 1 PM. Anyway I guess I can fixed. Again, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: "2:00 PM" is -2:22 in difference from now while "7:00 PM" is 2:38 in difference in your example. Do you want to constrain the times to only be in the future? This is not clear from your explanation.

Comment: So sorry if I wasn't clear enough. Think about an old person scheduler who should be notified about the next pill taken time. (always in the future)

Comment: If there are *only* items in the past for some id, should one of them still be shown? And which one - the closest in the time, the one occuring earliest in the day or some other criteria?

Comment: It must be shown only the closest in the time. Let me give you an example:

Med1 (id:1) - ['9am', 1pm', '5pm', '9pm']
Med2 (id:2) - ['11am', 3pm', '5pm',  '7pm', '11pm']

Now() = 16:48PM

Result that we must show is: 
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "time": "5:00 PM"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "time": "7:00 PM"
  }
]

Comment: I guess you changed it, so I would say that now works as expeted. Isn't it?

Comment: Your example doesn't answer my question. What I'm asking is if i.e. current time is `"5:00 PM"` and we for id=1 only have the times `["1:00 AM", "3:30 AM", "4:50 PM"]` should we show no values (since there are no times in the future in the same day), the time "1:00 AM" (since it will be the one that will occur next, though the next day) or "4:50 PM" (since it is closest in absolute difference, though in the past)?

Comment: Sorry. Thanks for your example. The answer for that example will be: 1:00AM which is the closest time in the future. (after 5:00 PM)

Comment: I have updated the code now. Does it work as expected?

Comment: I just implemented it. It does work like a charm! Thank you very much for all your effort! It just became part of my application.